# Functions that integrate to lnx

Tags: integration

I was told that functions can only integrate to something involving the natural logarithm if the power of the denominator is $1$, how true is this statement, because I am not sure if it is incorrect. For example, if we had $\int\frac{2x}{x^2} \; dx$ (I know we can simplify the integrand but I wont in this case), It will integrate to $\ln|x^2|$ or $2  \ln|x|$, even when the denominator has a power of 2. Am I being stupid and misunderstanding the meaning of power in this case or was what I was told originally false?
Thanks!!

Comment: Do the change of variable $y = x^2.$ What do you notice?

Comment: It is not meant this way. What is meant are functions like $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ for which we need the arc-tangent.

Comment: The "Power" of the denominator becomes 1? With the derivative of y on the top, meaning the integral is just $ln|y|$ + $c$

Comment: A better example to see that "degree of denominator=1" is not true is $f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ which cannot be simplified but can still be integrated with ln , antiderivate is $\ln(x^2+1)$

Comment: Thanks for your comment peter, the only thing i am a bit iffy about is what "degree" are you referring to, the entire denominator is raised to the power of 1, but x is raised to the power of 2. I feel like this is where the misconception lies, as the denominator itself is power of 1.

Comment: With degree , of course I mean the degree of the polynomial (here $x^2+1$)

Comment: I believe thats the answer to a different question I was asking, I am on about the power of the denominator as a whole, which now that I think about it doesnt really make much sense, as you could make the argument that everything is just raised to the power of 1 anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140734/discussion-between-mathguy-and-peter).

Comment: OK, I understand, you mean something more complicated like $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$. If I remember right, those cases can be somehow reduced to the case that we just have the polynomial (not with a higher power). I am however out of this kind of calculations, someone else might clarify it.

Comment: If the integrand is $\sum\limits_n\frac1{x-a_n}$, like with $\frac1{x^2+1}$ after partial fractions, then the integral is $\sum\limits_n\ln(x-a_n)$. $\frac1{x^2}$ cannot be put into this form. Right?